# xml comments inside xml elements

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, openxml, xml-validation

I want to know if it is legal to have XML comments inside any xml elements ?
For e.g. is the below xml comment legal ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE MSWord [<!-- multiple
     line
     comment -->] >
```

W3 org @ http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments says : 
Comments may appear anywhere in a document outside other markup; in addition, they

> may appear within the document type declaration at places allowed by
>   the grammar

So is my example above is legal.If yes, please guide if xml comments can exists inside any other xml element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion might be because you haven't understood the precise meaning of the term "XML element".

Yes, it is legal to have a comment anywhere within the content of an XML element (that is, between the start and end tags): but not within a start or end tag.

For example, you cannot have a comment between two attributes in a start tag. For example, the following is not well-formed.

```
<a b="3" <!-- not 4!--> c="5"/>
```

The text you are citing says that in the DTD, comments are allowed only where the grammar specifically permits them.

The grammar for your example is

```
[28]    doctypedecl    ::= '<!DOCTYPE' S Name (S ExternalID)? S?
                           ('[' intSubset ']' S?)? '>'    
[28b]   intSubset      ::= (markupdecl | DeclSep)*
[29]    markupdecl     ::= elementdecl | AttlistDecl | EntityDecl
                           | NotationDecl | PI | Comment
```

This tells us that what appears between the square brackets must be an `intSubset`, and that a `Comment` is a legal `intSubset` because it is a legal `markupDecl`.